# receiveTimeout Breaks the communication channel after inactivity?

Tags: wcf, timeout

**Hi,**

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS that has the following binding config :

```
 <binding name="netTcpRegular" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:00:20" sendTimeout="00:20:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

When the client(that holds the channel open) have logged in to the WCF service the channel will throw a faulted exception after 20 secon and Im not doing anything att all, not even commuinicating with the service? SO after 20 sec of inactivity the communication will fail.

The receiveTimeout should only affect when a call is in progress right? So how could it timout when doing nothing but having the channel open and ready for doing service call?

**Edit:**

By using the WCF log I get this exceptions:

```
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyTest-1-129811288584315020</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PreReadConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PreReadConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
```

---

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyTest-1-129811288584315020</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PreReadConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PreReadConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.GetPendingMessage()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.EndReceive()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
```

**Edit:**

Clientside binding :

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyClientServiceRegular" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:00:30" receiveTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false"/>
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: What is your client-side binding configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6042539/175679)

Comment: Seems like you have set the recieveTimeout (receiveTimeout="00:00:20" )to be 20 seconds due to which the connection is being dropped by the server. Can you set to a value higher than 20 seconds.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it solves the problem BUT I dont get it, receiveTimeout is acording to MSDN a timout on how long a call may take to reveive and for me this means that if I send a message with 2GB of size then I will have to increase reveiveTimout becouse the data will take som time to send of the network. In this case Im doing nothing att all? after 20 sec from the last call to the service I will get the exception? This sounds more like a inactivityTimeout?

Comment: I do have a keepAlive operation that is called every 9 minutes from client to service to keep the connection alive but this will not trigger within 20 sec ofcourse.

Comment: @SnowJim Can you indicate if a correct answer has been achieved, if you require more information, let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missunderstand the [meaning of ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx). It is "the interval of time that a connection can remain inactive, during which no application messages are received, before it is dropped". To extend this to infinity you need to [enable reliable sessions](http://nogeekhere.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/why-will-wcf-client-be-disconnected.html). Hope this clears it up.

Edit:
[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/) is further description, i think the property you are after is sendtimeout

Comment: p.s. default is 10 minutes for recievetimeout property

Comment: It is possible to set the ReceiveTimout to infinite, this is the setting I used before but it did not feel right. If I however need a long lasting session then it is the only setting I should use.

Comment: @SnowJim yes, this is the setting you need to make your session "long lasting"

Comment: reliableSession is not needed when using TCP binding according to the MSDN doc.

Comment: @SnowJim Please could you give me a link to this

Comment: @SnowJim [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx) MSDN soc suggests otherwise

Comment: Here is the link i read it at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx

Comment: @Idgorman, I can´t see that your MSDN article states that reliableSession should be turned on? It is off by default for TCP?

Comment: @SnowJim If you want an your connection to stay open idefinitely then do [this](http://nogeekhere.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/why-will-wcf-client-be-disconnected.html) else forget about ReliableSession. By defualt it will be turned off. To turn it on do: `<reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The receive timeout is how long it waits for all data to be received.

The time starts running as soon as the chanel is open, it does not detect the first byte that you send and start the timer then.

It is a bit like a taxi that starts the meter when you wave it down, not when you get in.