# TransactionCompleted and Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I use the Castle Windosr and its WcfFacility as IoC container and for creating WCF clients. The generated clients only seem to work when I configure them with singleton lifestyle. The code is called in a Transaction.TransactionCompleted event handler.

```
internal sealed class ViewsEventServicesGateway : IViewsEventServicesGateway
{
    private readonly Lazy<CreatedEventService.V3_1.ISystemStructureViewCreatedEventService> viewCreatedEventService;

    public ViewsEventServicesGateway(Lazy<CreatedEventService.V3_1.ISystemStructureViewCreatedEventService> viewCreatedEventService)
    {
        this.viewUpdatedEventService = viewUpdatedEventService;
    }

    public void RaiseCreated(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        viewCreatedEventService.Value.Raised(new CreatedEventService.V3_1.RaisedNotification(null, CreatedEventService.V3_1.RaisedNotificationAssembler.ToContract(ids)));
    }
  }
```

Castle is configured as shown below:

```
  windsorContainer.Register(WcfClient.ForChannels(model).Configure(r => r.LifestyleTransient()));
```

This results in the following error when calling the client.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ist aufgetreten.
HResult=-2147467259
Message=Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
Source=System
ErrorCode=10054
NativeErrorCode=10054
StackTrace:
    bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,   SocketFlags socketFlags)


System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags) + 0x6d Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.TimeSpan timeout, bool closing) + 0xd0 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x84 Bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.IConnection connection, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDecoder decoder, System.ServiceModel.IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, ref System.Runtime.TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper) + 0xe4 Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IConnection connection = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection}, System.ArraySegment<byte> preamble, ref System.Runtime.TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper) + 0x23d Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IConnection connection, ref System.Runtime.TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper) + 0x55 Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x21d Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x68 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x2e4 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x2e4 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0xdd Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x2e4 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.ExecuteMessage(object target, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCall = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message}) + 0xaa Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeChannel(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCall) + 0x219 Bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage message = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message}) + 0x1c0 Bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData msgData, int type) + 0x1f4 Bytes   
Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll!Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientActivator.GetChannelCreator.AnonymousMethod__1() + 0x4c Bytes    
Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll!Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfChannelHolder.WcfChannelHolder(Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.ChannelCreator channelCreator, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.IWcfBurden burden, System.TimeSpan? closeTimeout) + 0x90 Bytes
Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll!Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientActivator.Instantiate(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context) + 0x137 Bytes  
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context) Zeile 66 + 0x10 Bytes C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden) Zeile 80 + 0xe Bytes   C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, bool trackedExternally) Zeile 81    C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, Castle.MicroKernel.IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) Zeile 70 + 0xf Bytes  C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, bool requiresDecommission, bool instanceRequired, out Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden = null) Zeile 148 + 0x29 Bytes C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, bool instanceRequired) Zeile 93 + 0x16 Bytes  C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler handler, System.Type service, System.Collections.IDictionary additionalArguments, Castle.MicroKernel.IReleasePolicy policy) Zeile 742 + 0x16 Bytes C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(System.Type service, System.Collections.IDictionary arguments, Castle.MicroKernel.IReleasePolicy policy) Zeile 234 + 0x16 Bytes  C#
Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve<Views.CreatedEventService.V3_1.ISystemStructureViewCreatedEventService>() Zeile 77 + 0x28 Bytes C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<Views.CreatedEventService.V3_1.ISystemStructureViewCreatedEventService>.CreateValue() + 0x1f1 Bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<Views.CreatedEventService.V3_1.ISystemStructureViewCreatedEventService>.LazyInitValue() + 0x20c Bytes  
...
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.VolatileEnlistmentPreparing.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalEnlistment enlistment = {System.Transactions.Phase1VolatileEnlistment}) + 0x15c Bytes    
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.TransactionStateVolatilePhase1.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction tx) + 0xf7 Bytes  
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.PreparingEnlistment.Prepared() + 0x11a Bytes    
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory.DistributedTransactionContext.System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification.Prepare(System.Transactions.PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment = {System.Transactions.PreparingEnlistment}) Zeile 126  C#
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.VolatileEnlistmentPreparing.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalEnlistment enlistment = {System.Transactions.InternalEnlistment}) + 0x15c Bytes  
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.TransactionStatePhase0.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction tx) + 0x97 Bytes  
System.Transactions.dll!System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit() + 0x18e Bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TransactionInstanceContextFacet.Complete(System.Transactions.Transaction transaction, System.Exception error) + 0x85 Bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TransactionInstanceContextFacet.CompletePendingTransaction(System.Transactions.Transaction transaction, System.Exception error) + 0x72 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TransactionRpcFacet.Complete(System.Exception error) + 0xb2 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TransactionBehavior.ResolveOutcome(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x4ba Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ResolveTransactionOutcome(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc = {System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc}) + 0xc2 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x50 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x16a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x146 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x17b Bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(bool isOperationContextSet = false) + 0x17e Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request = {System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.DuplexRequestContext}, bool cleanThread, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x7ee Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x1e2 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0xdb Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously) + 0x17a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x11d Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 Bytes 
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously) + 0x17a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(object state) + 0x82 Bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(object state) + 0x174 Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 Bytes 
System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) + 0xc5 Bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessFrameBody(int readBytes, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) + 0x109 Bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ReadCallback(System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest}) + 0xea Bytes  
System.dll!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(int bytes) + 0x32 Bytes 
System.dll!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult transportResult) + 0x9a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously) + 0x17a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(object state) + 0x6a Bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs) + 0xde Bytes 
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError socketError, int bytesTransferred, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags flags) + 0xbc5 Bytes 
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) + 0x40 Bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode = 0, uint numBytes = 573, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP = 0x000000a6a0964860) + 0x96 Bytes
```

How is Castle supposed to work with System.Transactions? If I use the singleton lifestyle the calls to the WCF client work correctly. I can't use singleton lifestyle because the client are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register LazyOfTComponentLoader as described [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx).
Also, you may be making plenty of connections.
Make sure your max connections parameter is in order. [Here is an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042539/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-with-wcf)

Good luck!